# SQL Sync Verification in WPF

Tags: sql, wpf, synchronization, data-integrity

So I am designing an WPF application that needs to support offline functionality.
That means I will have a local database that syncs with the master database when available. My questions is in regards to the integrity of the data sync. I want to verify that the changes that are being synced to the master database are actually being made in the master database. Vise versa as well. What ways should I approach this issue. It may be worth noting that I am by no means a DBA and have just trouble shooting experience when dealing with SQL.

Comment: You should say what is your RDBMS both local and master database.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming you have SQL server as master and SQL express on WPF you need do several things and the best I can do is point you a tutorial

[Tutorial: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Express](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700(v=sql.110).aspx)